# Buffer overflow to jump to a disabled function

Tags: c, linux, assembly, buffer-overflow

I'm getting a hard time with this buffer overflow assignment. The code **adm.c** is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// define to allow administrative access, undef to restrict
#undef ADMINISTRATIVE 
//#define ADMINISTRATIVE

// function prototypes for "main.c" functions

int main (int argc, char *argv[]);
void list(void);
void add(void);
void quit(void);
void delete(void);
void deleteall(void);
void normal(char *user);
void administrative(char *nothing);
void debug(char *nothing);
void rot13(char *user, char *rot13pwd);

typedef void (*menufunctype)(char *);
typedef void (*userfunctype)(void);
typedef void (*adminfunctype)(void);

// jump table for non-administrative functions
userfunctype userfunc[3] = {add, list, quit};

// jump table for administrative functions
adminfunctype adminfunc[5] = {delete, deleteall, add, list, quit};


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

  menufunctype menufunc[3]={debug, administrative, normal};
  char rot13pwd[20];
  char user[20];
  char pwd[20];

  printf("Enter authorization code: "); fflush(stdout);
  gets(pwd);
  printf("Enter username or \"admin\" for admin functions: "); fflush(stdout);
  gets(user);

  // authenticate user
  rot13(user, rot13pwd);

  if (strcmp(pwd, rot13pwd)) {
    puts("Authentication FAILED.  Access denied.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  // passed authentication, now display debug, normal or
  // administrative menu.  If administrative access is prohibited by
  // compile-time "ADMINISTRATIVE" symbol, then don't allow admin
  // under any circumstances.

  if (! strncmp("debug", user, 5)) {
    (*menufunc[0])(user);
  }
  else if (! strncmp("admin", user, 5)) {
#if defined(ADMINISTRATIVE)
    (*menufunc[1])(0);
#else
    puts("NO ADMINSTRATIVE ACCESS AVAILABLE--SEE YOUR SYSTEMS ADMINISTRATOR.");
#endif
  }
  else {
    (*menufunc[2])(user);
  }
}

// menu for users with non-administrative access
void normal(char *user) {
  char buf[40];
  char normalaccessfile[20]=".normal_access";
  char choice[2];
  int ch;

  // audit trail
  sprintf(buf, "echo %s >> %s", user, normalaccessfile);
  system(buf);

  while (1) {
    puts("\n##### MENU ######\n");
    puts("[0] Add a record");
    puts("[1] List all records");
    puts("[2] Exit\n");
    printf("Choice: "); fflush(stdout);
    gets(choice);

    // audit trail
    sprintf(buf, "echo %c >> %s", choice[0], normalaccessfile);
    system(buf);

    ch = atoi(choice);
    if (ch < 0 || ch > 2) {
      puts("Invalid choice.\n");
    }
    else {
      (*userfunc[ch])();
    }
  }
}

// menu for administrators
void administrative(char *nothing) {
  char buf[80];
  char administrativeaccessfile[80]=".admin_access";
  char choice[2];
  int ch;

  while (1) {
    puts("\n----- RESTRICTED ADMIN MENU -----\n");
    puts("[0] Delete a record");
    puts("[1] Delete all records");
    puts("[2] Add a record");
    puts("[3] List all records");
    puts("[4] Exit\n");

    printf("Choice: "); fflush(stdout);
    gets(choice);

    // audit trail
    sprintf(buf, "echo %c >> %s", choice[0], administrativeaccessfile);
    system(buf);

    ch = atoi(choice);
    if (ch < 0 || ch > 4) {
      puts("Invalid choice.\n");
    }
    else {
      (*adminfunc[ch])();
    }

  }
}


// menu for debug account
void debug(char *nothing) {

  // implement debug menu later...

  // Marjorie: CHANGE THIS BEFORE RELEASE: MAJOR SECURITY HOLE!
  system(nothing);
}


// USER FUNCTIONS

// list all records
void list() {
  puts("*** LIST ***");
}

// add a record
void add() {
  puts("*** ADD ***");
}


// ADMINISTRATIVE FUNCTIONS

// delete a record
void delete() {
  puts("*** ADMIN: DELETE ***");
}

// delete all record
void deleteall() {
  puts("*** ADMIN: DELETE ALL ***");
}


// UNRESTRICTED

// quit
void quit() {
  puts("*** BYE ***");
  exit(1);
}


// ROT13 calculation
void  rot13(char *user, char *rot13pwd) {
  int i;
  char cap;

  for (i=0; i < 20; i++) {
    rot13pwd[i] = user[i];
    cap = rot13pwd[i] & 32;
    rot13pwd[i] &= ~cap;
    rot13pwd[i] = ((rot13pwd[i] >= 'A') && (rot13pwd[i] <= 'Z') ? 
           ((rot13pwd[i] - 'A' + 13) % 26 + 'A') : rot13pwd[i]) | cap;
  }
  rot13pwd[20]=0;
}
```

The problem is that I have to jump to the administrative function but it is disabled in the code. I have to figure out how to bypass `#undef ADMINISTRATIVE` and get inside the function somehow. So far I have figured out the password for the admin user which is nqzva and have disasembled the main function  but I'm kind of lost... :(

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000400784 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400785 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400788 <+4>: sub    $0x90,%rsp
   0x000000000040078f <+11>:    mov    %edi,-0x84(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400795 <+17>:    mov    %rsi,-0x90(%rbp)
   0x000000000040079c <+24>:    movq   $0x400b04,-0x20(%rbp)
   0x00000000004007a4 <+32>:    movq   $0x4009cb,-0x18(%rbp)
   0x00000000004007ac <+40>:    movq   $0x4008aa,-0x10(%rbp)
   0x00000000004007b4 <+48>:    mov    $0x400d68,%eax
   0x00000000004007b9 <+53>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x00000000004007bc <+56>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000004007c1 <+61>:    callq  0x4005f0 <printf@plt>
   0x00000000004007c6 <+66>:    mov    0x200c83(%rip),%rax        # 0x601450 <stdout@@GLIBC_2.2.5>
   0x00000000004007cd <+73>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x00000000004007d0 <+76>:    callq  0x400690 <fflush@plt>
   0x00000000004007d5 <+81>:    lea    -0x80(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000004007d9 <+85>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x00000000004007dc <+88>:    callq  0x400670 <gets@plt>
   0x00000000004007e1 <+93>:    mov    $0x400d88,%eax
   0x00000000004007e6 <+98>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x00000000004007e9 <+101>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x00000000004007ee <+106>:   callq  0x4005f0 <printf@plt>
   0x00000000004007f3 <+111>:   mov    0x200c56(%rip),%rax        # 0x601450 <stdout@@GLIBC_2.2.5>
   0x00000000004007fa <+118>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x00000000004007fd <+121>:   callq  0x400690 <fflush@plt>
   0x0000000000400802 <+126>:   lea    -0x60(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400806 <+130>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000400809 <+133>:   callq  0x400670 <gets@plt>
   0x000000000040080e <+138>:   lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rdx
   0x0000000000400812 <+142>:   lea    -0x60(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400816 <+146>:   mov    %rdx,%rsi
   0x0000000000400819 <+149>:   mov    %rax,%rid     
   0x000000000040081c <+152>:   callq  0x400b76 <rot13>
   0x0000000000400821 <+157>:   lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rdx
   0x0000000000400825 <+161>:   lea    -0x80(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400829 <+165>:   mov    %rdx,%rsi
   0x000000000040082c <+168>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x000000000040082f <+171>:   callq  0x400680 <strcmp@plt>
   0x0000000000400834 <+176>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000400836 <+178>:   je     0x40084c <main+200>
   0x0000000000400838 <+180>:   mov    $0x400db8,%edi
   0x000000000040083d <+185>:   callq  0x400600 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400842 <+190>:   mov    $0x1,%edi
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x0000000000400847 <+195>:   callq  0x400610 <exit@plt>
   0x000000000040084c <+200>:   lea    -0x60(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400850 <+204>:   mov    $0x5,%edx
   0x0000000000400855 <+209>:   mov    %rax,%rsi
   0x0000000000400858 <+212>:   mov    $0x400de0,%edi
   0x000000000040085d <+217>:   callq  0x400620 <strncmp@plt>
   0x0000000000400862 <+222>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000400864 <+224>:   jne    0x400875 <main+241>
   0x0000000000400866 <+226>:   mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rdx
   0x000000000040086a <+230>:   lea    -0x60(%rbp),%rax
   0x000000000040086e <+234>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000400871 <+237>:   callq  *%rdx
   0x0000000000400873 <+239>:   jmp    0x4008a8 <main+292>
   0x0000000000400875 <+241>:   lea    -0x60(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400879 <+245>:   mov    $0x5,%edx
   0x000000000040087e <+250>:   mov    %rax,%rsi
   0x0000000000400881 <+253>:   mov    $0x400de6,%edi
   0x0000000000400886 <+258>:   callq  0x400620 <strncmp@plt>
   0x000000000040088b <+263>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0x000000000040088d <+265>:   jne    0x40089b <main+279>
   0x000000000040088f <+267>:   mov    $0x400df0,%edi
   0x0000000000400894 <+272>:   callq  0x400600 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400899 <+277>:   jmp    0x4008a8 <main+292>
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x000000000040089b <+279>:   mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rdx
   0x000000000040089f <+283>:   lea    -0x60(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000004008a3 <+287>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x00000000004008a6 <+290>:   callq  *%rdx
   0x00000000004008a8 <+292>:   leaveq 
   0x00000000004008a9 <+293>:   retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

I thought about exploiting `system(nothing);` inside the `debug()` function and I was able to run a C executable I created called **debug** when I use the user debug and qroht as the password but I can't see how that would help me to get inside the administrative function unless somehow I can call the administrative function from that C executable (for now it just show "Hello World!" when I execute **adm.c** the program).

I also have this perl script that allows me to access to the normal menu (I'me guessing this is the way but I'm going to need the correct string to be able to overflow the program and jump between addresses):

```
perl -e 'print pack("H*","6e61716572660A616e647265730A");' | ./adm
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Since the menu entry is read with `gets` **it is full of security holes**. `gets` is no longer part of the C standard for that reason. You should be able to craft a buffer exploit based on the use of `gets` alone that will allow you to access the admin function addresses. Search on `gets` exploits. I don't have a quick string to offer, but there are many out on the web. Good luck.

Comment: this line: void delete(void); is using a key word (from C++) suggest using a different name.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin why don't focus on the problem and try to get balls out talking about deprecated functions?  While this guy takes care of not passing strings longer than the buffer size gets code has been around for a long long time (64bit time)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple guide for you:

1. Everything is read in using the gets function, so it's trivial to overwrite the menufunc array (assuming that your compiler puts it in a higher memory address in the stack frame. Based on the disassembly it does.)
2. Put a break point inside main at e.g. the line: gets(user);
3. Use gdb to print the address of the "administrative" function.
4. Use gdb to print the addresses of the user buffer as well as the menufunc array on the current stackframe.
5. Calculate their relative positions, so you know how much you need to write data past the end of the user array to overwrite menufunc[2]. (Depending on how well you read assembly, you can also calculate this straight from the disassembly you posted)
6. Give a username that writes the correct address (i.e. the address of the function "administrative" into menufunc[2] being careful with endianness here). Note that you need to pass a username containing non-printable chars. Of course, you need to make sure that the rot13 of the password you give also matches the username.

This is almost a step-by-step guide, so I leave it as an exercise how to fill in the gaps.

Answer (score -1):

The main reason you cannot get into the administrative code is that you have `#ifdef`'d it in the preprocessor pass, so it **has not been compiled** into the program.  This has the same effect of commenting all the code or erasing it from the source file.

This means that you don't have that administrative code in the program, then, you cannot execute it.  Instead of making it depend on a preprocessor macro, just put a normal `if()` statement to make the program go through it or not depending on some check made online.

Comment: This is completely wrong. The only result of the `#if defined(ADMINISTRATIVE)` directive is that the administrative function **do not appear in the user menu**. It has nothing to do with whether `void administrative(char *nothing)` is compiled into the program. This is as it was intended for the problem.

Comment: But it does appear never then.  If you decide at compile time when some code is going to be compiled (I mean the switch code, not the function) How the function is to be called then?  You cannot make a preprocessor test to be useful at runtime, as it's made to allow you to decide what code is to be put into the final executable or not, not to make runtime decisions.  Only in the case you have two different programs, one for user and one for administrator (compiled with different values for the ADMINISTRATOR macro), is when you can have this to make sense.

Comment: As written, the code only hides the call to `(*menufunc[1])(0);` and substitutes it with the message displayed in the `#else` part. You can downvote me but you are not right.  Of course the function appears, but the call not, so what's the reason of it either?

Comment: The point is to use a buffer overflow to "call" the function even though it's never called in the code. This is done by replacing the return address on the stack of a currently executed function with the address of the entry point of the administrative function. This is how many security vulnerabilities "call" code that was not meant to execute.